# Geolocalization via Titanium

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, titanium

Hi I'm developing an app that needs the most accurate GPS localization. Using the method that uses "kitchen sink" to show all Titanium's possibilities it gives me the network geolocation, can I have the device detection?

PS: The project is actually developed for Android, but will be soon ported to iPhone.

Comment: Can post post the actual code? Also iPhone and Android behave differently so I would suggest starting with iPhone, it will be less painful

Comment: here is some sample code from my blog [http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/5764810716/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-forwardgeocoder-callback](http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/5764810716/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-forwardgeocoder-callback)

Answer (score 2):

So, to clarify, you're basing your code off of [this example](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/geolocation.js)? And the issue is that you are getting network-based geolocation, instead of GPS-based geolocation?

Have you tried replacing the `preferredProvider` with `Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS`, instead of the string "gps"? As in:

```
Ti.Geolocation.preferredProvider = Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS;
```

Comment: I think the constant maps to gps

Comment: but even if i write ".PROVIDER_GPS" if there is not GPS connection it gaves me the last network location, can I avoid that? 
even a simple pop up error would be good to me, but i don't know witch which event fire it

Comment: So (again, a clarification on the question here), you want location detection from GPS and *only* GPS? If no GPS service is available, you want to trigger some error path instead? In other words, you don't want network geolocation, even if a GPS service is not available?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [TiStudio](http://preview.appcelerator.com) instead of TiDeveloper you can use the sample project GPS to start with. It's bundled in the download so just fire it up and use that code as a working copy to learn from. It's android ready as well :-)

Comment: whoops, try my.appcelerator.com to get the new release of TiStudio 1.0 that came out yesterday